# MATLAB Zoom then plot new data

Tags: matlab, plot, zooming

I create a a simple timeseries plot. Then I zoom in. When I zoom in, I'd like to calculate the mean of the zoomed areas Y data, and plot it on the same figure with the original Y data. I have tried the following code, but what it does it erase the original Y data, and only plots the mean data.

```
d = rand(1,length(t));
f = figure;ta = plot(t,d)
he = zoom;
guidata(ta,struct('d',d't',t,'axes',ta));
he.ActionPostCallback = @calcMean;

function calcMean(obj,evd)
data = guidata(obj);
newLim = evd.Axes.XLim;
tStart = round(newLim(1));
tEnd = round(newLim(2));

Croppedt = find(data.t(tStart:tEnd));
CroppedD = ones(1,length(Croppedt)).*mean(data.d(Croppedt));
plot(gca,data.t(tStart:tEnd),CroppedD,'r')
end
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `hold` the plot to stop it erasing the original data.

Put the following code after you create the 1st plot.

```
hold on
```

Ideally you should tell hold which axes to hold:

```
f = figure;
ax = axes ( 'parent', f );
plot ( ax, .... )
hold ( ax, 'on' )
```

While not strictly necessary (Matlab will assume `gca` is the current axes if not specified - it is good practice and likely to avoid some bugs in the future if you write more complex code etc...

**edit**
You need to save the handle to the zoomed plot, something like (untested)

```
function calcMean(obj,evd)
  data = guidata(obj);
  newLim = evd.Axes.XLim;
  tStart = round(newLim(1));
  tEnd = round(newLim(2));

  Croppedt = find(data.t(tStart:tEnd));
  CroppedD = ones(1,length(Croppedt)).*mean(data.d(Croppedt));
  if isfield ( data, 'zoomHandle' ) 
    delete ( data.zoomHandle )
  end
  data.zoomHandle = plot(gca,data.t(tStart:tEnd),CroppedD,'r');
  % you then need to update the guidata to save the handle.
  guidata(obj,data);
```

end

Comment: Works! One last question: How can I delete the current line so that I can draw a new one? The way it currently works is it keeps drawing a new line each time I zoom in/out, which is the way it was designed.